# R and ggplot 2: How to set quantile limits for axes in ggplot2 R plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use quantiles to limit the x axis the the first 99 quantiles to get a scatter plot looking something similar to the below (for illustration purposes ONLY - teh plot on teh right was created  using the fixed limits 0,500 on xlim):

```
ggplot(aes(x=volume,y=log10(price)),data= diamonds)+
  geom_point()+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,500))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(aes(x=volume,y=log10(price)),data= diamonds)+
  geom_point()+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(quantile(diamonds$volume<diamonds$volume, 0.99)))
```

which produces this:

[image: scatterplot fig1.]

and

```
ggplot(aes(x=volume,y=log10(price)),data= diamonds)+
  geom_point()+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(quantile(diamonds$volume, 0.99)))
```

which produces this:

[image]

I want to avoid tampering with the actual data or creating a new dataset. Can anyone point to where I am going wrong?

```
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(quantile(diamonds$volume, 0.99)))
```

produces very similar results, so I suspect that the issue is how I am defining the quantiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that `xlim` expects a vector with two elements: min and max.

max is defined by `quantile(diamonds$x, 0.99)`
while min can be `min(diamonds$x)`

```
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)

ggplot(aes(x=x,y=log10(price)),data= diamonds)+
  geom_point()+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(diamonds$x), quantile(diamonds$x, 0.99)))
```

[image]

I used `x` instead of `volume` since the `diamonds` data set in my version of `ggplot2` (2.2.1) does not contain the column `volume`.